# Isomorphisms of k-tensor product

Tags: tensor-products

Let $k$ be a field, $V$ an infinite-dimensional $k$-vector space, and $R:= End_k(V)$, the ring of endomorphisms.

Why does this hold:

$M_{n+2}(R)\cong End_k(k^{n+2})\otimes_k R ?$

I do not know if this is a universal property or if it only holds for $R:= End_k(V).$

To specify, equality is a $k$-vector space isomorphism.

Comment: Maybe it is clear to the experts, but what does $M_{n+2}(R)$ denote?

Comment: $M_{n+2}(R)$ is the vector space of $n+2 \times n+2 $ matrices with entries in $R$.

Answer (score 0):

It's a more general phenomenon:

For any $k$-algebra $R$ and $m\in\Bbb N$, we have a natural isomorphism 
$$R^m\cong k^m\otimes_k R$$
of vector spaces over $k$. 
Now apply it with $m=(n+2)\times(n+2)$.